# How to refresh the src of <img /> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<img src="test.php" />
```

where test.php generates an image with a random number.

Itried :

```
$('#verifyimage').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    });
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can force a refresh by appending a random string at the end, thus changing the URL:

```
$('#verifyimage').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src')+'?'+Math.random());
});
```

Comment: Eww. No, don't. Set appropriate caching response headers on the server instead.

Comment: `Cache-control`, `Expires`, et al. only work once a HTTP request is received - the above is simply to force the client to make that request. In the absence of a `Image.reload` (AFAIK), this was the simplest method to make a new request

Comment: would suggest substring on the src attribute to a "?" so that after the first time, it doesn't keep appending more querystring data...

Comment: This is the same strategy as in jeerose's reply in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104949/how-to-reload-refresh-an-elementimage-in-jquery

Comment: @KPrime This is great!! I struggled many hours to make it work. Thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

Add a timestamp or a random number:

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
$(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src') + '?' +timestamp );
```

Comment: The timestamp is a better solution! You can't rely on random not to be be the same sometimes.

Comment: tried this but having problem in chrome. Image src gets appended with the timestamp but thumbnail is not getting refreshed.

Can you suggest me anything on this?

Comment: @RohanPatil - There is an obvious issue here - you want to **add or update** a query **parameter** - this code is just a partial solution - it assumes there are no query parameters to begin with (In addition, I suspect it only works once).

Answer (score 6):

Taking KPrimes great answer and adding in trackers suggestion, this is what I came up with:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // we have both a image and a refresh image, used for captcha
    $('#refresh,#captcha_img').click(function() {
       src = $('#captcha_img').attr('src');
   // check for existing ? and remove if found
       queryPos = src.indexOf('?');
       if(queryPos != -1) {
          src = src.substring(0, queryPos);
       }    
       $('#captcha_img').attr('src', src + '?' + Math.random());
       return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In test.php set the headers of `Content-Type:` to `image/jpeg`