# how to refresh list of photos after uploadify jquery

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I want to do a sort of photo editor,
i use uploadify to upload images

here are my files: http://www.mediafire.com/?3uzzgx5onzn

the problem is: after upload the images i dinamicaly generate a thumb .. When I click on it it show me the large pictures in another page, i want to show the picture in a div or a paragraf! after I refresh the page is working! why?

from my php script i recive only the image name (response)
after UploadifyComplete i append this:

```
jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).attr('id') + ID).html('<a href="uploads/' + response + '"><img width="60px" height="60px" src="uploads/' + response + '" alt="' + response + '" /></a>');
```

to this:

```
                        jQuery(queue).append('<li class="uploadifyQueueItem">\
                            <span class="fileName">' + fileName + ' (' + byteSize + suffix + ')</span>\
                            <div class="uploadifyProgress">\
                                <div id="' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + ID + 'ProgressBar" class="uploadifyProgressBar"><!--Progress Bar--></div>\
                            </div>\
                        </li>');
                }
```

and the result will be:

```
<div class="uploadifyQueue">
  <ul id="mainftpQueue">
    <li class="uploadifyQueueItem">
     <a href="uploads/Winter.jpg"><img height="60px" width="60px" alt="Winter.jpg" src="uploads/Winter.jpg"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i putt all the images in 1 php array
after all images uploaded i want to refresh the div where this code is:

```
                <div class="uploadifyQueue">
            <?php
            if ($_SESSION['files']){
                print '<ul id="mainftpQueue">'."\n";
                    foreach($_SESSION['files'] as $image ):
                        print '<li class="uploadifyQueueItem">'."\n";
                            print '<a href="uploads/'.$image.'"><img height="60px" width="60px" alt="'.$image.'" src="uploads/'.$image.'"></a>'."\n";
                        print "</li>\n";
                    endforeach;
                print "</ul>\n";
            }
            ?>
            </div>
```

i try with:

```
$('#mainftpQueue').load(location.href+" #mainftpQueue>*","");
$('#mainftpQueue').load("/ #mainftpQueue li");
```

buth no succes

sorry 4 my bad english.. if any 1 can edit this

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't just load a part of a page like that. You'd need to use PHP. However, you could change the src attribute of the image tag dynamically to the thumbnail. Something like this will work:

```
var d = new Date();
$("img").each(function(i){
    this.attr("src", "/"+this.attr('src')+"?"+d.getTime());
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104949/how-to-reload-refresh-an-elementimage-in-jquery/2104998#2104998)

The date part is to make sure it isn't cached by the browser. This iterates through all the images on the page and reloads them.

Comment: My code will simply go wherever you were planning to put the `$('#mainftpQueue').load(location.href+" #mainftpQueue>*","");`.

Comment: :(( is not working, it stops after upload
i get this:
assignment to undeclared variable d
[Break on this error] d = new Date();

Comment: Try `var d = new Date();` instead.