# Jquery .animate issues with cached site

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a div that is being slide from off the page with .animate automatically when you come to the page. I have it working on first visit, but when the site becomes cached and you revisit, the function seems not to fire. A few refreshes eventually gets it going again but I need it to be reliable.

It seems to be that I need to be able to "reset " the script so even on a cached site it fires again.

This is the script I'm running now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#logo_fixed img").bind("load", function () { $(this).animate({"left": "+=434px"}, "slow"); });

});
```

The img is position:absolute  and set off the page in the css

I have tried a few different ways of doing this, But I have the issue of also needing the image to be loaded before it is slide in. And don't want it to be the last thing to come up.

I also tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#logo_fixed img').load(function(){

        $(this).animate({"left": "+=434px"}, "slow")

    });   

});
```

Same results, if the site is cached it wont fire, but a reload will get it working.

If Anyone has any help I would greatly appreciate it thanks!

Comment: can you check to see if the image is loaded, and if it is, run the same animation?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this technique:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#logo_fixed img').load(function(){
        $(this).animate({"left": "+=434px"}, "slow")
    });
    d = new Date();
    $("#myimg").attr("src", $("#myimg").attr("src")+d.getTime());
});
```

That would force the image to reload each time.

[How to reload/refresh an element(image) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104949/how-to-reload-refresh-an-elementimage-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

When the image is cached, it is "loaded" (ie the load event fires) before the document.ready fires.

You can use $("#logo_fixed img").live instead of .bind.  Put the code outside the document.ready function.

I would do the following:

```
var logoLoaded = false;

$("#logo_fixed img").live("load", function () { logoLoaded = true });

$(document).ready(function() {

   if(!logoLoaded){

        $('#logo_fixed img').load(function(){

             $(this).animate({"left": "+=434px"}, "slow")

        });
   }    
   else
   {
        $('#logo_fixed img').animate({"left": "+=434px"}, "slow")
   }

});
```

Not the most succinct code, and probably can be improved a bit, but that will ensure that your animate event doesn't fire off too early (waits 'till document.ready) but takes into account the image loading before document.ready.