# Refresh <img> in jQuery periodically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Similar to [How to reload/refresh an element(image) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104949/how-to-reload-refresh-an-elementimage-in-jquery) but not at the same time.

I have a webcam that saves images every 2 seconds rather than streaming.  Using jQuery (or straight JS) I want to refresh just the image element.

Should be easy, but all my searches show the refresh on request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#myimg").attr("src", "/myimg.jpg?"+new Date().getTime());
},2000);
```

Comment: Where you have "myimg.jpg" I have a JS global var set with the path, how do I integrate that?  I've tried $("#myimg").attr("src", imagePath+"?"+d.getTime()); but the image disappears

Comment: i wrote `new Date().getTime()`. if you use `d.getTime()` you'll have to first assign it `var d = new Date();`

Answer (score 3):

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) is a timer that will execute a function everything x milliseconds

```
setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    $("#myimg").attr("src", "/myimg.jpg?"+d.getTime());
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Where you have "myimg.jpg" I have a JS global var set with the path, how do I integrate that?  I've tried $("#myimg").attr("src", imagePath+"?"+d.getTime()); but the image disappears

Answer (score 3):

You must force the browser to realod the image instead of taking it from cache. You can do it by changing the url, adding a useless parameter that changes each time, for example a timestamp.

```
$('img.webcam').each(function() {
    var jqt = $(this);
    var src = jqt.attr('src');
    src = src.substr(0,src.indexOf('?'));
    src += '?_ts=' + new Date().getTime();
    jqt.attr('src',src);
});
```

Execute this snippet inside a timer or on a click or both or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    $("#myimg").attr("src", "/myimg.jpg?"+d.getTime());
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Where you have "myimg.jpg" I have a JS global var set with the path, how do I integrate that?  I've tried $("#myimg").attr("src", imagePath+"?"+d.getTime()); but the image disappears

Answer (score 1):

Add a timestamp to the image source it will refresh.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("img").each(function(){
       var timeStamp = (new Date()).getTime();
       $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src") + timeStamp );
    });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Unlike the other answers this would increase the size of the URL every 2 seconds (because you keep appending, not replacing). It wouldn't take too long before you had a URL thousands of characters long.