# jQuery error() function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, error-handling

I want to display two images that I have no idea when they will be generated. So I want to use the jquery error function to keep checking if the images exist, and display each. Following code works on every browser except IE. Why does it not work on IE, really appreciate your help.

```
<style type="text/css">
DIV#loader {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

DIV#loader.loading {
    background: url(spinner.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image_names = new Array(2);
    image_names[0] = 'a.jpg';
    image_names[1] = 'b.jpg';
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for ( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        showImage(image_names[i], divs[i]);
    }
});

function showImage(src, div) {
    var img = new Image();
    $(img).load(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(div).removeClass('loading').append(this);
        $(this).fadeIn();
    }).error(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(img).attr('src', src);
        }, 2000);
    }).attr('src', src);
}
</script>
```

This is the HTML body

```
<body>
<h1>Image Loading</h1>
<div id="loader" class="loading"></div>
<div id="loader" class="loading"></div>
</body>
```

It seems like IE does not know the image is generated if it does not exist when the page first loads

Comment: When you use script debugger in IE, which line of code shows the error?

Comment: Id should be unique `loader` used with more than one element.

Comment: Just checking, try to call `$(img).attr('src', src);` without setTimeout.

Comment: It did not show any errors when I was using script debugger in IE

Comment: Try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2104998/1329367

Comment: As a side note avoid duplicate IDs like @SheikhHeera suggests, IE is much stricter to these kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching caused the problem. Changed the src to:

```
$(img).attr('src', src + "?" + (new Date().getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `$(document).ready({})` part;  throws an error in ie for me.  Changing it to `$(function(){});`  seems to work for me at least in IE.

Comment: which version of IE are you using? I first used `$(function(){});`, and it did not work for me.. I am using IE 9

Comment: ??? not sure what that has to do with it?  I did it in jsfiddle and it runs every time.  Don't have large enough images to maybe test it as well as it should be but the concept should be the same.  http://jsfiddle.net/uvtDm/1/

Comment: Yea, it worked if images exist, but i have no information about when the images will be generated, and I want to display it immediately if one is generated. So the page should keep checking if image files are present, and they are there, then display them, if not, keep checking. If delete one image file, then open the page, after you put it back, it wont show on the page if you use IE, but it worked on other browsers.