# How can I reload a specific html tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to happen is that the `class="profile-pic"` will refresh/reload before or on the dialog closes because the image source changes.

This is my code:

```
$('.change-profile-pic').click(updateProfilePicture);
function updateProfilePicture(){
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        resizable:false,
        modal:true,
        width:225,
        buttons: {
            'Upload':function(){
                $('#upload-image').ajaxForm({ 
                        target: '.new-profile-pic'
                }).submit();
            },
            'Done':function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'update-profile-pic.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: { file_path: $('.new-profile-pic img').attr('src') },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == 'Success'){
                            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML To be reloaded:

```
<p class="profile-pic ">
                    <a href="#"><img class="change-profile-pic ui-corner-all" src="<?php echo $user['user_profile_path']; ?>" alt=""></a>
                </p>
```

HTML form:

```
<div title="Change profile picture" id="dialog" class="dialog-change-profile-pic">
            <div class="new-profile-pic">

            </div>
            <form id="upload-image" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload-image.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
                <input class="profile-pic-name" name="uploadedfile" type="file">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: What should contain `#loadthis` after the reload?

Comment: You can refresh the div instead of reload

Comment: an image, i have to do something to it

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'reload'? What should happen with the element?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific in your question

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104949/how-to-reload-refresh-an-elementimage-in-jquery

Does that help?

Comment: the div refresh? -------

Answer (score 1):

You can write up the close event function which fires as soon as the close event fires..

```
<p class="profile-pic ">
                    <a href="#"><img class="change-profile-pic ui-corner-all" src="<?php echo $user['user_profile_path']; ?>" alt=""></a>
                </p>

close: function(event, ui) { 
    // Change the src attribute here with the newer source.. That should do 
 }
```

You can also use the beforeClose event

```
beforeClose: function(event, ui) { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is the image src wrapped in a PHP tag? Couldn't that just be static HTML? Your browser most likely has the image cached so if the image changes on the server side and you just want to reload it then you could do something like

```
$('.goButton').click(function() {
    $('#loadThis' img)[0].src = 'resources/default-male.png?' + Math.random();
});
```