# File Caching: Query string vs Last-Modified?

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache, caching

I was fooling around with ways of caching my website's assets and noticed most websites similar to mine use query strings to override caching (e.g.: /css/style.css?v=124942823)

Afterwards, I noticed that whenever I saved my style.css file, the last-modified headers were "updated", making the query string unnecessary.

So I wonder:

- Why do so many websites use the "query string" method, instead of just letting the last-modified header do its work?
- Should I unset the Last-modified header and just work with query strings? (Is there any particular advantage to this?)

Comment: Chrome's caching is VERY aggressive and I've seen it refuse to grab the updated css/js files, even if the tab is closed, a new one is opened, or even days later, across multiple computers.  I recently had to fall back to putting the version in a query string for our Azure hosted webapp.  Although it's possible the server isn't sending correct header dates, I haven't verified it yet.

Comment: Chuck Norris uses query strings.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### TL;DR

> Why do so many websites use the "query string" method, instead of just letting the last-modified header do its work?

Changing the query string changes the url, ensuring content is "fresh".

> Should I unset the Last-modified header and just work with query strings?

No. Though that's *almost* the right answer.

---

There are three basic caching strategies used on the web:

- No caching, or caching disabled
- Using validation/conditional requests
- Caching forever

To illustrate all three, consider the following scenario:

A user accesses a website for the first time, loads ten pages and leaves. Each page loads the same css file. For each of the above caching strategies how many requests would be made?

### No caching: 10 requests

In this scenario, it should be clear that there isn't anything else influencing the result, 10 requests for the css file would result in it being sent to the client (browser) 10 times.

#### Advantages

- Content always fresh
- No effort/management required

#### Disadvantages

- Least efficient, content always transferred

### Validation requests: 10 requests

If [Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) or [Etag](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) are used, there will *also* be 10 requests. However 9 of them will only be the headers, and no body is transferred. Clients use conditional requests to avoid re-downloading something it already has. Take for example the css file for this site.

The very first time the file is requested, the following happens:

```
$ curl -i http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Mon, 12 May 2014 07:38:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d3fa9eddf76d614f83603a42f3e552f961399880311549; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.sstatic.net; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800
Last-Modified: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 22:09:37 GMT
ETag: "8026e7dfc064cf1:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
Expires: Mon, 19 May 2014 07:38:31 GMT
CF-RAY: 1294f50b2d6b08de-CDG
.avatar-change:hover{backgro.....Some KB of content
```

A subsequent request for the same url would look like this:

```
$ curl -i -H "If-Modified-Since:Wed, 30 Apr 2014 22:09:37 GMT" http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Mon, 12 May 2014 07:40:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d0cc5afd385060dd8ba26265f0ebf40f81399880411024; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.sstatic.net; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800
Last-Modified: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 22:09:37 GMT
ETag: "8026e7dfc064cf1:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
Expires: Mon, 19 May 2014 07:40:11 GMT
CF-RAY: 1294f778e75d04a3-CDG
```

Note there is no body, and the response is a [304 Not Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5). This is telling the client that the content it already has (in local cache) for that url is still fresh.

That's not to say this is the optimal scenario. Using tools such as [the network tab of chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) allows you to see exactly how long, and doing what, a request takes:

[image]

Because the response has no body, the response time will be much less because there's less data to transfer. But there *is* still a response. and there *is* still all of the overhead of connecting to the remote server.

#### Advantages

- Content always fresh
- Only one "Full" request sent
- Nine requests are much slimmer only containing headers
- More efficient

#### Disadvantages

- Still issues the maximum number of requests
- Still incurs DNS lookups
- Still needs to establish a connection to the remote server
- Doesn't work offline
- May require server configuration

### Caching forever: 1 request

If there are no etags, no last modified header and only an expires header set far in the future - only the very first access to a url will result in any communication with the remote server. This is a [well-known? best practice for better frontend performance](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires). If this is the case, for subsequent requests a client will read the content from it's own cache and not communicate with the remote server at all.

This has clear performance advantages, which are especially significant on mobile devices where latency can be significant (to put it mildly).

#### Advantages

- Most efficient, content only transferred once

#### Disadvantages

- The url **must** change to prevent existing visitors loading stale cached versions
- Most effort to setup/manage

### Don't use query strings for cache busting

It is to circumvent a client's cache that sites use a query argument. When the content changes (or if a new version of the site is published) the query argument is modified, and therefore a *new* version of that file will be requested as the url has changed. This is less work/more convenient than renaming the file every time it changes, it is not however without its problems,

[Using query strings prevents proxy caching](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/), in the below quote the author is demonstating that a request from browser<->proxy cache server<->website does not use the proxy cache:

> Loading mylogo.gif?v=1.2 twice (clearing the cache in between) results
>   in these headers:
>
> ```
> >> GET http://stevesouders.com/mylogo.gif?v=1.2 HTTP/1.1
> << HTTP/1.0 200 OK
> << Date: Sat, 23 Aug 2008 00:19:34 GMT
> << Expires: Tue, 21 Aug 2018 00:19:34 GMT
> << X-Cache: MISS from someserver.com
> << X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from someserver.com
>
> >> GET http://stevesouders.com/mylogo.gif?v=1.2 HTTP/1.1
> << HTTP/1.0 200 OK
> << Date: Sat, 23 Aug 2008 00:19:47 GMT
> << Expires: Tue, 21 Aug 2018 00:19:47 GMT
> << X-Cache: MISS from someserver.com
> << X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from someserver.com
> ```
>
> Here it’s clear the second response was not served by the proxy: the
>   caching response headers say MISS, the Date and Expires values change,
>   and tailing the stevesouders.com access log shows two hits.

This shouldn't be taken lightly - when accessing a website physically located on the other side of the world response times can be very slow. Getting an answer from a proxy server located along the route can mean the difference between a website being usable or not - in the case of cached-forever resources it means the first load of a url is slow, in the case of using validation requests it means the whole site will be sluggish.

### Instead version-control assets

The "best" solution is to version control files such that whenever the content changes so does the url. Normally that would be automated as part of the build process.

However a near-compromise to that is to implement a rewrite rule [such as](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/.htaccess#L623-L637)

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Filename-based cache busting                                               |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# If you're not using a build process to manage your filename version revving,
# you might want to consider enabling the following directives to route all
# requests such as `/css/style.12345.css` to `/css/style.css`.

# To understand why this is important and a better idea than `*.css?v231`, read:
# http://stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpe?g|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In this way a request for `foo.123.css` is processed by the server as `foo.css` - this has all the advantages of using a query parameter for cache busting, but *without* the problem of disabling proxy caching.

Comment: Hey, I'm in the process of implementing this and was wondering, why does this site, among others, use Query strings on their assets if many people insist this is a bad practice? Is there any other reason to add a "version" as a query string if it's not for cache busting? Thanks!

Comment: Probably just for convenience. Not using proxy caching is less relevant if you're using a cdn - though depending on the cdn it may even ignore the query string such that changing it has no effect. That'd be a question for meta.stackexchange.com to get a definitive answer.

Comment: "Don't use query strings for cache busting" - so then what about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541077/why-is-cache-control-attribute-sent-in-request-header-client-to-server#14544664)

Comment: @IvánSánchez what about it?

Comment: You have said that "Using query strings prevents proxy caching," but anyway most modern browsers sends the "Cache-Control: no-cache" header on the request (that prevents content to be proxy cached). Therefore, I see no disadvantage in using the querystring approach

Comment: @IvánSánchez The context here is if you _do_ want proxy caching to not unknowingly disable it. `most modern browsers sends the "Cache-Control: no-cache"` - Reference please. AFAIK this statement is not true, if your browser is doing that in a blanket fashion it's through explicit/implicit choice.

Comment: @AD7six the reference is in the first comment I wrote. Did you open it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541077/why-is-cache-control-attribute-sent-in-request-header-client-to-server#14544664

Comment: I did - comments on an answer to a question on a different topic don't qualify as a reference :). If that's your sole basis for asking the question here, I recommend further research - and if you wish then writing an answer with your findings. Reminder: what you asked about is more or less moot/irrelevant with cache-forever strategy.

Comment: "Don't use query strings for cache busting" is an outdated 2008 concept.  http://www.bizcoder.com/caching-resources-with-query-strings

Comment: @DavidLin So true. Nowadays [even SO itself uses this method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112182/how-does-se-determine-the-css-and-js-version-parameter).

Answer (score 2):

The Last-Modified header is applied differently across browsers, but generally the browser will issue a conditional GET request that the server must respond to if the cache needs to be updated. For example, in Firefox...

> The "Last-Modified" response header can be used as a weak validator.
>   It is considered weak because it only has 1-second resolution. If the
>   "Last-Modified" header is present in a response, then the client can
>   issue an "If-Modified-Since" request header to validate the cached
>   document.
>
> When a validation request is made, the server can either ignore the
>   validation request and response with a normal 200 OK, or it can return
>   304 Not Modified to instruct the browser to use its cached copy. The
>   latter response can also include headers that update the expiration
>   time of the cached document.

By setting a timestamp (or fingerprint), you explicitly let the browser know when it needs to update its cache and you can then set very long expiration times.

It may be worth noting that the documentation on the rails asset pipeline (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) cites 3 advantages for fingerprinting over a querystring timestamp:

- Not all caches will reliably cache content where the filename only
  differs by query parameters
- The file name can change between nodes in multi-server environments.
- Too much cache invalidation

For more detail and best practices on caching:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching