# Web Browser in c# not displaying up to date css information

Tags: c#, html, css

I have a C# application with a webpage displaying a website. Upon recently overhauling the website (fairly simple website, not much on it) the application continues to use the old background and does not use the CSS of the new document. I suspect some form of caching is causing this problem, can anyone help me with it? (The website works fine in browser, but not in the application)

Comment: Set an unique link to your css, like styles.css?asdfdsgfjijwelrmsdnfjdsflks

Comment: What control are you using in the C# app to display the application?  The standard forms control leverages IE and so it's probably cached by IE.

Comment: What do you mean by this VMAtm? I have a separate CSS file which is linked to in the html.

Comment: AaronLS, How would I go about changing this?

Comment: @BilboBaggins You can force the browser to retrieve a new CSS by generating the HTML page with a different query string param to the end where the page links (`<link` tag) to the CSS.  See this for other strategies of cache invalidation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603023/file-caching-query-string-vs-last-modified

Comment: I would go with @VMAtm answer but with a date time as the query parameter so Ross doesn't happen in the future. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the cache of the webbrowser instance programatically:

```
webBrowser.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I also used in line <style>ing which worked, however much less elegantly.