# Random number file name in a HTML

Tags: html, random

I wanted to know how using a random number makes a difference when included in a file name which is being referenced in a html.

How is the first line of code different from the second one?

```
<script src="index.js?1481269289258"></script>

<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Any details/info on this would help.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Check out this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603023/file-caching-query-string-vs-last-modified

Comment: The number, is usually in the form of a unix timestamp or version.  This is appended to force the web browser to load a new (fresh) copy of the file as `foo.js?12345` is a different file than `foo.js?12346`, the browser would re-download `foo.js` updated copy replacing the locally cached version if any.  It's really a hack to trick browsers into reloading your script when they are too stubborn to give up the old copy.

Answer (score 2):

This is sometimes used to bypass caching. Typically the http server or caching layer (e.g. varnish) use query parameters in the cache key. Thus, adding a *unique* query parameter will serve the same file, but force a reload.

Comment: ... or to ensure that only the latest version of the script is cached (not forcing the browser to cache, but to ditch the old version if it had a cached copy and update with the new version) -- it doesn't actually prevent caching.  just bypasses the stubbornness of browser caches in most cases.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Though there you would typically use a versioning system, not a random number or string.

Comment: Random wouldn't help in that case :)

Comment: Correct  :)   (also tweaked my comment above)

Comment: Thanks Guys. So basically a cache buster?

Answer (score 1):

The random number force the navigator to reload the script. Otherwise it may run the script in cache.