# Return image by jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Somehow the code to setup src for image tag does not work at all.

But if I put directly url in browser or update page the url is working fine.

It seems like

```
var tsPath = '@Url.Action("UpdatedLogo", "Logo")';
$('#logo').attr("src", tsPath);
```

is not firing at all.

What I am missing?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Logo", "Users")',
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                // It is not working :(
                var tsPath = '@Url.Action("UpdatedLogo", "Logo")';
                $('#logo').attr("src", tsPath);

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Timeout error.");
            }
        });
```

**C#**

```
 public ActionResult UpdatedLogo()
        {
                // ... some code
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                        return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
                    }

        }
```

P.S. What I found that when I do it first time it happens and all next click dont have any effect. And at the same time no errors.

Could be that Browser is caching image somehow? Or what it is?

Comment: what does `tsPath` returning?

Comment: I'm afraid you just said `user\Updatedlogo`.It should be return `user\Updatedlogo.extension' and does file exists there? jsfiddle?

Comment: check the url of image in javascript. try to add '\' in start of the url if it does not exist.

thanks

Comment: Well ' \ ' exists coz @Url.Action generate it properly.

Comment: Yes either a JSfiddle or your HTML might be of help here.  We currently cannot rule out that there isn't a `$('#logo')`

Comment: What does a `console.log(tsPath)` give you after `var tsPath = '@Url.Action("UpdatedLogo", "Logo")';` ?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker It gives '/Logo/UpdatedLogo'

Comment: ok - without any extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found whatsup.

Here is an answer [How to reload/refresh an element(image) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104949/how-to-reload-refresh-an-elementimage-in-jquery)

I did following

```
var tsPath = '@Url.Action("UpdatedLogo", "Logo")';
$('#logo').attr("src", tsPath + "?&d=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
```

Yeah! :)

Comment: ok - yes that would certainly bust the cache but I'm still not sure whether your original was returning an extension?