# Refresh an arbitrary image with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have an auto-generated form that also handily displays thumbnails. I want to add a button beside the image that will refresh it if it is updated. I want to take cached images into account.

I add a button easily enough:

```
// add a refresh button to image previews
$('a[href*="/thumbs/"]').after('<div class="refresh-image"><button class="refresh-image-button">Refresh</button></div>');
```

And since I'm okay if the refresh button refreshes all of the stale images I try to append a query string to the image src (deleting an old query string if it exists):

```
// attach refresher to button
$(".refresh-image-button").click(function() {
    $('img[src*="/thumbs/"]').attr("src", $(this).attr("src").split('?',1)+'?'+Date.now());
});
```

However, I can't really do this because here $(this) doesn't refer to the matched image, and I can't do a split operation within this jquery match anyway.

How *do* I do it?

As a **bonus** if anyone has a ref to decent auto refresh image code, that would be helpful.

This builds on a simpler SO inquiry [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104949/how-to-reload-refresh-an-elementimage-in-jquery).

Comment: Pls post your code with relevant (sample maybe) markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the collection:

```
$(".refresh-image-button").click(function() {
    $('img[src*="/thumbs/"]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").split('?',1)+'?'+Date.now());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g68gxu93/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a variable with the new trailing parameter separately like :

```
$(".refresh-image-button").click(function() {
    var newAttr = $('img[src*="/thumbs/"]').attr("src").split("?")[0] + "?ver=" + new Date().getTime();
    $('img[src*="/thumbs/"]').attr("src", newAttr);
});
```

see **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j9gy0k61/)**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something almost precisely like @Moogs answer.

```
addRefreshButtons();

// NICEITIES

function addRefreshButtons() {
  // add a refresh button to image previews
  $("div.refresh-image").remove();
  $('a[href*="/thumbs/"]').after('<div class="refresh-image"><button class="refresh-image-button">Refresh</button></div>');
  // attach refresher to button
  $(".refresh-image-button").click(function() {
      refreshThumbnails();
  });
}

function refreshThumbnails() {
    $('img[src*="/thumbs/"]').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        var newSrc = src.split('?',1)+'?'+Date.now()
        $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
    });
}
```