# Evaluating Javascript Expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I was trying to update the image being displayed after an image file with same name overwrote the previous file and came across this link:[Reload/refresh an element(image) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104949/how-to-reload-refresh-an-elementimage-in-jquery)

I had a scope element "imgUrl" which I was passing in the data-ng-src as:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{imageUrl + '?' + GetTimeStamp()}}">
```

This thing worked but I also tried this:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{imageUrl}} + '?' + {{GetTimeStamp()}}">
```

And this didn't work. Whats the difference between these two expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opening brackets `{{` indicate that an angular expression begins, and the closing brackets `}}` indicate that it ends. Everything outside of the brackets is considered to be a plain text attribute. Therefore, the `+` becomes just a text symbol between the two expressions, rather than acting as the string concatenation operator.

Comment: "Everything, that follows the closing brackets" - to be precise, it's "everything outside of `{{ }}`"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You are right, that was rather ambiguous, since anything can follow the brackets. Edited the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Kazimieras And if I hadn't used + and just this: {{imageUrl}}?{{GetTimeStamp()}}. Had it been fine?

Comment: @VishalChugh This is also fine. In this case you are just evaluating two simpler expressions instead of a more complex one.

Comment: @VishalChugh if you find that your question has been answered, it would be great if you could mark it as accepted :)