# Changing marker image on pointerenter event Heremaps

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change a marker image on hover in here maps. Im doing in this way:

```
     noiseMarker.addEventListener('pointerenter', changeMarker);

 function changeMarker(evt) {
        evt.target.getIcon().c.src = activeMarker;
}
```

In my marker object I can see that the image source has been changed, but on the map it is not showed. Is there anyone with experience in here maps that can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload/refresh an element(image) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104949/how-to-reload-refresh-an-elementimage-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use the setIcon function?
You have to pass it a abstractMarker.

```
function changeMarker(evt) {
    evt.target.setIcon(activeMarker);
}
```

Documentation on markers: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-marker.html

Comment: what if i have two hyperlink for two marker on the map and i am showing the first marker using setCenter. Second marker is far from first one. If I hover on the second hyperlink, how do i shift the map position to that marker using the above facility