# jquery and swap images

Tags: jquery

I have this simple toggle function to open/close information.  I want to add a image next to it so that it shows expanded or closed.  I tried this method but nothing is happening.  What am I missing?

```
$('#slick-software').click(function() {
   $('#slickbox-software').toggle(400);
   $('#slick-img').attr('src') == "/images/up.png" ? "/images/down.png" : "/images/up.png";
   return false;
});

...
...

<a href="#" id="slick-software">
    <img id="slick-img" src="/images/up.png" border="0" align="absmiddle" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <b>Software</b><br>
    </a>
<div id="slickbox-software">
    text here
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A nicer solution would be to use CSS for your up/down image, you could include it as a background image on the #slick-software element (with some left padding applied to it). You could then toggle a class in your click handler to either change the background image, or preferably change the background position of a [CSS sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). I also prefer to call preventDefault than returning false to override the default click behaviour as returning false stops [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).

```
$('#slick-software').click(function(e) {
   $('#slickbox-software').toggle(400);
   $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then in your css, something like:

```
#slick-software{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  background: url(img/toggle.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

#slick-software.expanded{
  background-position: 0 -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is here, I think:

```
$('#slick-img').attr('src') == "/images/up.png" ? "/images/down.png" : "/images/up.png";
```

You just check 'src' attribute here, but don't actually change it.

Use the following instead:

```
var newSrc = $('#slick-img').attr('src') === "/images/up.png" ? "/images/down.png" : "/images/up.png";
$('#slick-img').attr('src', newSrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var src_img = ($('#slick-img').attr('src')=="/images/up.png") ? "/images/down.png" : "/images/up.png";
$('#slick-img').attr('src', src_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to force the image to refresh once you have changed the src.  There's a question here which is very similar with a few decent answers:

[How to refresh the src of <img /> with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1997901/484072)